# How to find files without a directory path in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, directory

I have a directory:
*test/test1/file1.sh
test/file2.sh*

What i need as a output:
*file1.sh
file2.sh*

I need to hide the dir.path at the output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your criteria which files should be included in the output, but if you want to print the names of all `*.sh` files under `test/`, you can do:

```
$ find <path_to_test_folder> '*.sh' -printf %f\\n
```

(If you're running it from the root folder of the search, you can drop the `<...>` part.)